# UDP connection - Socket programming in C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp

I have a specific equipment (IP : 192.168.0.10 port 3000 - it's a signal receiver) that must be controlled through UDP. I should be able to send this equipment basic commands such as 'reset'; 'log' ; 'run'...

After some struggle and the gentle help of stackoverflow I managed to communicate with my equipment using netcat. It now works perfectly. I used the command **nc -u 192.168.0.10 3000** after changing the computer eth IP. (I'm under Linux).

Now, and that's the goal, I need to do the same as netcat, but, using C language. Since I'm a beginner I tried myself using internet and wrote this:

```
    /* Standard Linux headers */
    #include <stdio.h> //printf
    #include <string.h> //memset
    #include <stdlib.h> //exit(0);
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <errno.h>


/* DEFINE */ 
#define SERVER "192.168.0.10"
#define BUFFLEN 1024  //Max length of buffer
#define PORT 3000   //The port on which to send data


int main (void)
{

/*
   **  Definition of the local variables.
*/
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; /* Server Socket address structure*/
 /* short int status = 0; /* internal status return*/
 /*  unsigned short int return_status = 0; /* the returns status value */

  char recepbuff[BUFFLEN];
  char cmd[BUFFLEN];
  int socket_fd;

/* 
    **  Initialization of the local variables.
*/
 memset(recepbuff, '0' ,sizeof(recepbuff)); /*pareil que bzero*/


/*
   **  Creating the socket
   **  call socket (it creates an endpoint for communication and
   **                returns the socket descriptor.
   **                 To create an UDP socket here are the param
   **                 The protocol family should be AF_INET
   **                 The protocol type is SOCK_DGRAM
   **                 The protocol should beset to default i.e.
   **                 DEF_PROTOCOL which is default so 0. );
*/

if ( (socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0) ) < 0 ) /* return 1 if okay */
  {
    printf("ERROR opening socket");
  }

  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; /*Define the domain used*/
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); /*Declare port #PORT to be used*/
  /*serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); /*Permit any incoming IP address by declaring INADDR_ANY*/

// Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form
if(inet_pton(AF_INET, SERVER, &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0) 
  {
    printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n");
    return -1;
  }
  
if (connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
  {
    printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
    return -1;
 }
else
{
    printf("\n Connected \n");
}

/* Messaging*/   
  while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter command : ");
        gets(cmd);
         
        //send the message
        if ( (sendto(socket_fd , cmd , strlen(cmd) , 0 , (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) ) < 0 )
        {

          printf("DEBUG_CMD: Failed sending cmd\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("DEBUG_CMD : CMD * %s * SENT\n", cmd);
            puts(cmd);
        }
        
        //receive a reply and print it
        //clear the buffer by filling null, it might have previously received data
        memset(recepbuff, '0' ,sizeof(recepbuff));
        printf("mini-debug memset done\n");

        //try to receive some data, this is a blocking call
        if ((recvfrom( socket_fd, recepbuff, strlen(recepbuff), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) ) < 0)
        {

          printf("DEBUG_RECEP: Failed received cmd\n");
        }
        else

        {
            printf("DEBUG_RECEP : CMD RECEIVED\n");
        }
         puts(recepbuff);
    }

close(socket_fd);
return 0;

}
```

So, I launch my program, and it seems to be correctly connected. I type my command, a simple **reset** and then nothing happens. Like if it's blocked at the **recvfrom** (because the "mini debug memset done" is printed). And I can't find any clue about what I am doing wrong.

EDIT : Corrected the strlen in the recvfrom => same thing
In fact, I'm not even sure that I'm using the right method and even if I'm really "connected"...

Comment: This `recvfrom(..., strlen(recepbuff), ...)` tells `recvfrom` to receive `0` bytes ... :-) Which seems to make it sit and wait.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue: Please Do Not Use `gets()`. It is know to allow the user to overflow the input buffer. And it isn't even C any more. Use `fgets()` instead. In your case you might want to use `fgets(cmd, sizeof cmd, stdin);`. Please note the buffer read might contain a trailing  new-line (`'\n'`)

Comment: As @alk notes - it is network code with strlen() in it, so it's borken.

Comment: *"Now, and that's the goal, i need to do the same as netcat"*. No, HacHac, you do not. Either you want to do the same as that specific command does -- which lets you interactively type commands and read the responses from the device --, or you want to integrate the command sending and response receiving into a larger program. Which is it? In either case, you can make it very robust by using pthreads (as UDP is very asynchronous). No, they're not hard; they're actually easy, if used correctly. If you'll tell us your **underlying** goal, I could maybe spin some example code for you.

Comment: @MartinJames: The irony in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48115051/udp-connection-socket-programming-in-c#comment83214038_48115051) is probably not obvious to anybody.

Comment: @MartinJames: anybody --> everybody

Comment: @alk So if i understannd well, my recepbuff is empty so i ask to receive 0 bytes? So why, when a change strlen(recepbuff) with BUFFLEN(=1024) it does the same thing ? What do i misunderstand ? 

Thank you !

Comment: @NominalAnimal So let me explain. I have on computer, receiving datas from 2 equipments, it then processes this data, to send different commands to 4 other units. All in serial port.
My ultimate goal is to update this program from serial to UDP (+ other things). So yes, sending/receiving into a larger program. I will have a look on pthreads but will enjoy some example !

Thank you !

Comment: I don't know if this is a copying error, but you're memsetting to `'0'` (the character zero) instead of `'\0'` (the value 0, NUL)

Comment: @Hasturkun no, it was a mistake ! Thank you ! (still did not solved my problem)